# How to relatively increment/decrement the current value to a user chosen value?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing a small function that will let the user set a value for a window.

By default, the window lets you cycle forward/backward between 5 possible values:

- `Red`
- `Green`
- `Blue`
- `Black`
- `White`

The window does not let you set its value through absolute means. For example you cannot just set it to `Blue`, you have to cycle back or forward until you get to `Blue`. No means of mouse interaction, only:

- `Up` key to cycle forward
- `Down` key to cycle backwards
  The values wrap around, so when you get to `White`, it goes back to `Red` and vice versa.

I want to solve this problem with AHK, by associating each of the 5 values with a number.

- `1` = `Red`
- `2` = `Green`
- `3` = `Blue`
- `4` = `Black`
- `5` = `White`

---

```
SetState(Value := ""){
    Value := Value = "Red"      ? "1"
            :   Value = "Green" ? "2"
            :   Value = "Blue"      ? "3"
            :   Value = "Black" ? "4"
            :   "5"

    StateIs := GetState()  ;Retrieves the current state, a value such as "2" for when its "Green"

    NewState    :=  StateIs (-|+) = Value          ; This is pseudo  code
    If Incrementing or "+"                      ; This is pseudo  code
        SendInput,% "{Up " NewState "}"
    If Decrementing or "-"                      ; This is pseudo  code
        SendInput,% "{Down " NewState "}"     
    }
```

So something like `Space::SetState("Green")` will set it to `Green` straight away, by sending the Nth amount of `Up`/`Down` keys needed.

The part I am stuck on is `NewState := StateIs (-|+) = Value`.  I cant quite figure out, just how I can get AHK to intelligently increment/decrement to arrive at a predetermined mathematical sum?

I wracked my head at this, Any input would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to work we could create a "send up or down" function that takes in an integer `i`:

- when `i` is positive it would send down `i` times;
- when `i` is negative it would send up `-i` times;
- when `i` is 0 it would do nothing.

#### In AHKv2:

```
SendUpOrDown(times){
    if(times != 0){ 
        Send "{" ((times > 0) ? "Down " : "Up ") ((times > 0) ? times : -times) "}"
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

;for testing
F9::{
    SetState("Black")
}

;for testing
GetState(){    
    return "Red"
}

SetState(stateString){
    static stateStrToInt := Map(
        "Red", 1,
        "Green", 2,
        "Blue", 3,
        "Black", 4,
        "White", 5,
    )
    static SendUpOrDown(times){
        if(times != 0){ 
            Send "{" ((times > 0) ? "Down " : "Up ") ((times > 0) ? times : -times) "}"
        }
    }

    i := stateStrToInt[stateString]
    j := stateStrToInt[GetState()]
    SendUpOrDown(i - j)
}
```

---

Next, because your menu "loops around", we could send less keystrokes by comparing the amount of key strokes to the number of options divided by 2.

So for example we could rewrite `SetState` as:

```
SetState(stateString){
    static stateStrToInt := Map(
        "Red", 1,
        "Green", 2,
        "Blue", 3,
        "Black", 4,
        "White", 5,
    )
    static SendUpOrDown(times){
        if(times != 0){ 
            Send "{" ((times > 0) ? "Down " : "Up ") ((times > 0) ? times : -times) "}"
        }
    }

    static numberOfOptions := stateStrToInt.Count
    difference := stateStrToInt[stateString] - stateStrToInt[GetState()]

    if(difference > 0 && difference > numberOfOptions // 2 ){
        SendUpOrDown(difference - numberOfOptions)
    }
    else if(difference < 0 && difference < -numberOfOptions // 2){
        SendUpOrDown(difference + numberOfOptions)
    }
    else{
        SendUpOrDown(difference)
    }
}
```

This way if we want to go from `Red` to `Black`, we would go "-2" instead of "3", saving one `Send` command!